# Apiman X-Fowarded-For on Simple Header Policy

Tags: apiman

I'd like to know if there is some way to add the Client remote IP on my Request Header from API Man.

I need to add a Simple Header Policy with a "X-Forwarded-For" containing the client remote ip.

My backend is getting the APIMan IP as remote client, but what I need get to client IP.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom policy plugin and override `doApply` method to set the Client IP from `ApiRequest` object to the custom header like below.

```
 apiRequest.getHeaders().put("X-Forwarded-For", apiRequest.getRemoteAddr());
```

And add the new custom policy plugin to your services. This is a simple tutorial to create plugin